# How to get latitude and longitude of the selected location by user in Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

```
function dest()
{

var options = {
  types: ['establishment']
};


autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);


autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
 var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
 var cd= place.geometry.location;

}
```

But I am getting Error on execution as:
**place** is undefined.
**(
TypeError: place is undefined

var cd= place.geometry.location;
    )**
and I am defining my script as

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: This might be able to help you https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete for an example of how best to use Autocomplete in the Maps API.

autocomplete.getPlace() will not return a valid Place object until the user has entered one. You can tell when this happens by listening to the place_changed event on the autocomplete object.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  console.log(autocomplete.getPlace());
}
```